# Hyperlink in swing component with character wrap (combination of JEditorPane and JTextArea)

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, word-wrap

I want to put a hyperlink and some other text in a swing component. This component should be able to fit all of the text in its horizontal space (i.e. no horizontal scrollbars) by wrapping by words, and only by characters when words are too long to fit across the entire component. Parts of this can be accomplished using certain components:

`JEditorPane`s support hyperlinks. However, they don't break on characters and do weird things when placed in `JScrollPane`s.

`JTextArea`s can wrap by words or characters, but do not support hyperlinking.

Is there some combination of these components, or some way I can get one to act like the other?

Some of the other SO questions that I've looked at (for reference):

[Wrap long words in JTextPane (Java 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666727/wrap-long-words-in-jtextpane-java-7)
[JEditorPane inside JScrollPane not resizing as needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280106/jeditorpane-inside-jscrollpane-not-resizing-as-needed)
[How can I add a clickable URL in a JTextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001001/how-can-i-add-a-clickable-url-in-a-jtextarea)

**Note**: I am using java 8, and would prefer not to have to download anything, if possible.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a `JEditorPane` to break on characters if you add this to its stylesheet?

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

If you want to elaborate on the "weird things" that might be holding you back from using it, we can try to address those too.

Comment: My apologies, the "weird things" refers to the [second of the links that I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280106/jeditorpane-inside-jscrollpane-not-resizing-as-needed). The `JEditorPane` wwill expand to fill the `JScrollPane` and then won't shrink again when the window is made smaller.

Comment: Also, `word-wrap` has no effect.